# Use openpyxl to format the xlsx (number format, fit the text and shrink the texts)

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I want to use `openpyxl`(do not use other libs) to edit the xlsx with following code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
rows = [['name', 'This is number1', 'This is number2', 'longstr'],
['a', 312318.231, -2312.2, 'aaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaa'],
['a', 312318.231, -2312.2, 'aaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaa']
]
for row in rows:
    sheet.append(row)
book.save('text.xlsx')
```

and here is the result:

[image]

What I want are

1. Format the numbers in column 2, 3 with comma style (thousands separator) and decreasing into no decimal. I used `"{:,.0f}".format()` in the code, but the output in the xlsx becomes a string.
2. Let cells fit with the text for column 1, 2, 3
3. Shrink the texts to fit the cells for column 4 (not for title). In excel, the operations is
   `Format Cells -> Alignment -> Shrink to fit`

[image]

Above is the simplified example, in the real case we have thousands of rows and known number of columns (say 4 columns).

I am new in using `openpyxl` , could you help me to obtain my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**column format**

To control the number display format in Excel, you set the cell attribute like this:

```
cell.number_format = "0.0000" # 4 decimal places
```

**column width**

Set the width is similar, but as a column attribute:

```
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 12.5
```

Unfortunately, you need to calculate the width manually and there is no good way to do that. I found [an example on the web](https://bitbucket.org/jky/cpytoxlsf.py/src/8daa1d5cb54097b4a061f50961c96fe7efbc380b/cpytoxlsx.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) that list out all width metrics for Calibri 11 font (default in Excel). You can take a look on how the column width is calculated over there.

Comment: `cell.number_format = "0.0000"` how to set for the numbers in a specific column (table)? And how about the comma style (thousands separator)?

Comment: You need to loop through each cell. And the format string: check with [microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

For fit-to-shrink...

```
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(shrinkToFit=True, horizontal='center')
```

...should do it.